# Оператор is в python

Tags: python

```
>>>a=100
>>>b=100
>>>a is b
True
>>>a=300
>>>b=300
>>>a is b
False
```

Почему оператор is выдаёт разные значения? И для чего он нужен?

Comment: обычно целые числа из диапазона [-5, 256] кэшируются и имеют одинаковый id. [Здесь подробнее](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15172182/5741205)

Answer (score 3):

- оператор **==** проверяет равенство значений двух объектов
- оператор **is** проверяет идентичность самих объектов. Его используют, чтобы удостовериться, что переменные указывают на один и тот же объект в памяти

Python (CPython, если быть точнее) в целях производительности кеширует короткие строки и малые целые числа, поэтому возможны такие казусы:

```
>>> str1 = 'hello'
>>> str2 = 'hello'
>>> str1 == str2
True
>>> str1 is str2
True
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Оператор `is` - это в общем-то "синтаксический сахар".

```
a is b
```

По факту тут проверяется следующее:

```
id(a) == id(b)
```

Т.е. `is` проверяет, что `a` имеет тот же уникальный идентификатор, что и `b`, а значит обе переменные ссылаются на один и тот же объект.

Теперь о том, почему в каких-то случаях присваивание одинаковых значений приводит к тому, что переменные указывают на одни и те же объекты, а в каких-то нет. Это сильно зависит от реализации интерпретатора `Python`, и, как правильно заметил MaxU, под целые числа из диапазона от -5 до 256 включительно интерпретатор заранее выделяет место в памяти и даёт переменным ссылки на эти объекты. А под числа, не попадающие в диапазон, интерпретатор создаёт новые, отдельные объекты.

И это касается не только чисел. Если хотите больше знать, почитайте мега-разбор [What the f*ck Python!](https://github.com/satwikkansal/wtfpython), там много разных приколов `Python` объясняется, и этот случай там тоже разобран.